# Splitting string on dots but not on dots within round brackets

Tags: c#, regex, split

I would like to achieve the above but didn't manage it.

I already tried the regex `"\.(?![^(]*\))"` but it does not work so far.

I want to split the string `"replace(<<accountname>>.right(4), Saturn).invert()"` like this:

```
replace(<<accountname>>.right(4), Saturn)
invert()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a *matching* approach, i.e. match any one or more occurrences of a string between balanced parentheses or any char other than a `.`:

```cs
var output = Regex.Matches(text, @"(?:\((?>[^()]+|(?<o>)\(|(?<-o>)\))*\)|[^.])+")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(x => x.Value)
    .ToList();
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3A%5C%28%28%3F%3E%5B%5E%28%29%5D%2B%7C%28%3F%3Co%3E%29%5C%28%7C%28%3F%3C-o%3E%29%5C%29%29*%5C%29%7C%5B%5E.%5D%29%2B&i=replace%28%3C%3Caccountname%3E%3E.right%284%29%2C%20Saturn%29.invert%28%29). *Details*:

- `(?:`  - start of a "container" non-capturing group:

  - `\(` - a `(` char
  - `(?>[^()]+|(?<o>)\(|(?<-o>)\))*` - zero or more occurrences (backtracking into the pattern is disabled since the `(?>...)` is an atomic group, this way the pattern is efficient) of

    - `[^()]+|` - one or more chars other than a `(` and `)`, or
    - `(?<o>)\(|` - a `(` char, and a value is pushed on to Group "o" capture stack, or
    - `(?<-o>)\)` - a `)` char, and a value is popped off the Group "o" capture stack
  - `\)` - a `)` char
- `|` - or

  - `[^.]` - any char other than a `.` char
- `)+` - end of the group, repeat one or more times.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to really test this without some examples, but does this do what you want?

```
(?<!\()\.(?!\))
```

Explanation: It uses a negative lookbehind to ensure the character before the dot is not an opening parenthesis and a negative lookahead to ensure the character after it is not a closing parenthesis.

Comment: There is an example in the question, `replace(<<accountname>>.right(4), Saturn).invert()`, and the expected result is also shown. [It is clear](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5c%28%29%5c.%28%3f!%5c%29%29&i=replace%28%3c%3caccountname%3e%3e.right%284%29%2c+Saturn%29.invert%28%29) your regex is matching both the dots and will thus result in 3 splits (click the *Splits* tab on the bottom in the .NET regex tester).